# How to Query a nested field in Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

My firestore doc contain a field called `id`that is in a map called venue part of a collection called orders.

```
|-orders     //collection
        order  //doc
          venue {id:'12345'}.      Map in doc called venue that contains a string field called id
```

I want to use `isEqualTo` to query against this field. How do I reference the field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...
found the solution ..quite easy

In my case:

```
query.where('venue.id',isEqualTo: '12'),
```