# Query nested objects firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the orders from my db where the email property (which is inside the buyer object) is equal to the user's email; but I keep getting an empty array without orders.

```
const ProfileContainer = () => {
let { user } = useContext(AppContext)

const [orders, setOrders] = useState([])
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(orders)
}, [orders])

useEffect(() => {
    const db = getFirestore()
    const ordersRef = query(collection(db, 'orders'), where(('buyer', 'email'), '==', user.email))
    getDocs(ordersRef)
        .then(res => {
            setOrders(res.docs.map((order) => ({ ...order.data() })))
        })
        .finally(() => setLoading(false))
}, [user])

return (
    <>
        {loading ?
            <Spinner />
            :
            <Profile
                orders={orders}
                user={user}

            />
        }
    </>
)
}
```

This is my db [image: firebase schema]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dot notation to build the path to the nest field.

```
const ordersRef = query(
    collection(db, 'orders'),
    where('buyer.email', '==', user.email)
)
```

See also

- [How to Query a nested field in Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62833362/how-to-query-a-nested-field-in-firestore)
- [Update fields in nested objects in firestore documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49150917/update-fields-in-nested-objects-in-firestore-documents)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried that, but now this error is showing: "Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {seconds, nanoseconds}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: If you have a new problem, please make a new post to explain what's not working the way you expect.